# iTunes Connect add testers to group doesn't work

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am using test flight to add testers in this way:

`iTunnes Connect` > `My Apps` > `MyProject` > `TestFlight (tab)` > `NEW GROUP`

[image]

Then i chose add new user to this group:
[image]

The status is "-" i remembered it should be "**Invited**" `Resend the invite`, the tester can't received the invitation. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new app still the same error. Finally found how to solved it.

- Uploaded a new build.
- Under the `testFlight` tab choose the group `Beta` -> `Builds`
- Added the build just uploaded, start testing.

After this go back to `testers` then all testers changed from `-` to `Invited Resend Invite`